# Lotus Notes: Find out who created the database/replica?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

Is there a way in Lotus Notes to find who created the database or replica. Name of the user or server who created it.

I checked the db properties and cannot find anything like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way to do so:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/d6091795dfaa5b1185256a7a0048a2d0/bd985fb1c9ef61f68525799500596ab9?OpenDocument

Comment: hey i am using Lotus Notes 6.5 and I dont find anything like DBDesign class there

Comment: An idea: you can go thru all docs in the Notes database, even the design elements like the icon and then process the UpdatedBy field.

Comment: that will be doing investigation and may or may not be 100% correct. BUT question still stands,

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the logs (potentially from backup) when the replica was created?  It should be logged saying the ID that created the database replica.